# JQuery .change() slider values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with real time changing values inside script. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/h2pndbc7/

When I click loop it should do script from *if* section, but when i click back it should script from *else* section

```
$(document).ready(sliderFunction());
    var opcja = $("#select");
    var czas_animacji = 5;  
    var widthZdjec = 156; 
    var iloscZdjec = 4;  
    var ilosc = (iloscZdjec-1)*-widthZdjec;
function sliderFunction(){
    var slider = setInterval(
        function(){
            opcja.change(function(){
                if(opcja.val()=="loop"){
                    $(".zawartosc").children("img").first().animate({
                        marginLeft: ilosc,
                      }, czas_animacji*1000);
                    $(".zawartosc").children("img").first().animate({
                        marginLeft: "0",
                    },0*1000);
                } else {

                    $(".zawartosc").children("img").first().animate({
                        marginLeft: ilosc,
                      }, czas_animacji*1000);
                    $(".zawartosc").children("img").first().animate({
                        marginLeft: "0",
                    },2*1000);
                }
            })
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm just learning JQuery, can you tell me how it would look better?

Comment: [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is a standard JavaScript function that will cause your function to be called over and over and over at regular intervals (unless you've overridden it somewhere else).